# Could not find a method (View) in the activity class com.example.ivy.bienesraicesapp.PanelUsuarioActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

i have some problems with  a button method **"add"** because the activity is calling another class and i can't find where is the error.

AddPropiedadActivity.java with the next code:

```
public class AddPropiedadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_propiedad);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_propiedad);
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void add(View view){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TESTING  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

And the activity content_add_propiedad.xml with just one button with the onClick method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_propiedad"
    tools:context="com.example.ivy.bienesraicesapp.AddPropiedadActivity">

    <Button
        android:onClick="add"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:text="@string/titulo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but when i click the button get this error, because is calling to PanelUsuarioActivity and not to AddPropiedadActivity,even if i add my method in PanelUsuarioActivity the button works... so i want to fix this error and that the activity content_add_propiedad calling the java class AddPropiedadActivity:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method add(View) in
>   the activity class
>   com.example.ivy.bienesraicesapp.PanelUsuarioActivity for onClick
>   handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with
>   id 'btn_add'

Here is the other java class

```
public class PanelUsuarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_panel_usuario);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_propiedad);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: check your `activity_add_propiedad.xml` and remove the property `android:onclick` from `btn_add`

Comment: but if i remove the property onClick the button dont do the method

Comment: you can call setOnClickListener

Comment: i dont know why my activity_add_propiedad.xml is calling the class PanelUsuarioActivity.
activity_add_propiedad.xml should call the class AddPropiedadActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My error was in PanelUsuarioActivity when i call my Activity with setContentView. So i change that with a method and it works! :)!**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            openAlta();
    }
    });
}

public void openAlta( ){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddPropiedadActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```